# Multiple Relationship In Core Data to Entities of the Same Type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Say I have a business class

Business class has 3 relationships

menus are menus
brochures are brochures
images are images

They are all related to an image entity. Image entity has a business relationship which points to the business owning the menus, brochures, and images respectively.

What would be the inverse relationship of the business relationship then? Menus? Brochures? or Images?

Answer (score 1):

I think each relationship needs its own inverse, for data integrity reasons. So if you have menus, brochures and images, you need three inverses: businessForMenu, businessForBrochure, businessForImage.

If you need to be able to access the aggregate of those three things, you could then model the `business` relationship from image as a fetched property, selecting on Business, with the predicate

```
ANY menus == "$FETCH_SOURCE" OR ANY brochures == "$FETCH_SOURCE" OR ANY images == "$FETCH_SOURCE"
```

Comment: What about if I set that menus and brochures "inherit" from images.