# What happen when we inherits one entity from another entity in core data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have entities

Business
Image
Brochure
Menu

Business have relationship called Images. That relationship points to Image property. The inverse is BusinessRel, which is a relationship from Image to Business.

Now Brochure and Menu inherit Image entity. Image is the parent class of both brochure and menu. Image has an attribute called URL and one relationship, namely BusinessRel?

So does that mean Brochure and Menu automatically have Businessrel relationship?

I don't see that noticed in core data model. When I make Brochures which is a to many relationship between Business to Brochure, I do not see Businessrel as the inverse relationship.

So what does Menu and Brochure inherits from Image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Relationship In Core Data to Entities of the Same Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150819/multiple-relationship-in-core-data-to-entities-of-the-same-type)

Answer (score 0):

No u must get exact object from moc using fetch request and setup appropriate keys in u new managed object